# PyInstaller filenotfounderror and cannot import name only when run as systemd service

Tags: python, pyinstaller, systemd

I'm running a number of compiled PyInstaller applications as systemd services on Debian.

This works fine over ssh:

systemctl start service_name

However, if I enable these to run on boot, i.e.

systemctl enable service_name

I get all the common file not found errors, i.e.:

FileNotFoundError: 'cacert.pem' resource not found in 'certifi'

Is it normal the PyInstaller doesnt work with systemd services?

Answer (score 0):

After 8 hours of trying, adding this to crontab fixes the problem:

```
TEMP=/home/admin/
@reboot sleep 5 && /home/admin/app
```